# MySQL QUERY "LIKE" returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like

I'm using MySQL version 5.0.51a and PHP to access the database, and this query returns nothing when it should return at least 2 rows which match the LIKE condition.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'OR email LIKE    '%".$search."%' ORDER BY ".$order, $con);
```

The **$search** variable is '**Name**',

there is no problem with ORDER, $order or $con, i've already tried that, and there are 2 rows where the name is 'Name', but somehow it can't find those rows and it returns nothing.

Does anybody know where the problem is?

Comment: is your $search variable proper ??

Comment: also echo out your $order

Comment: have you tried without % operator

Comment: echo "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%' OR email LIKE '%".$search."%'  ORDER BY ".$order"; echo your query ans print here i think problem in your variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing double commas

```
$result = mysql_query("
                    SELECT 
                        * 
                    FROM user 
                    WHERE name LIKE '%{$search}%' OR email LIKE '%{$search}%' 
                    ORDER BY ".$order, $con);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly on the syntax as others have pointed out, here is another way:

```
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE '%{$search}%' IN (name, email )
 ORDER BY ".$order.','. $con)
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR email LIKE '%".$search."%' 
ORDER BY ".$order.','.$con);
```

Comment: @neeraj it seems you didn't saw closing (','), yes it is write I am just concatenating string.

Comment: There is .' before comma. But your actual string is being framed within double quotes ""