# PhpMyAdmin search returns row but Sql returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

when I search in the PhpMyAdmin an email of the style of

```
something@something.com
```

Using

```
LIKE %something@something.com%
```

It returns a row. But whenever I search it using an sql sentence, either from php or either executing the query from PhpMyAdmin

The query I'm using is

```
 SELECT * FROM tblMyTable WHERE field LIKE '%something@something.com%'
```

Can it be because of the @?

Thanks

Comment: SELECT * FROM tblMyTable WHERE field LIKE %something@something.com%

Comment: It still doenst return anything from the sql sentence

Comment: @Fibonacci : try it as `SELECT * FROM tblMyTable WHERE field LIKE '%something%'`

Comment: can you try SELECT * FROM tblMyTable WHERE field LIKE '%{something@something.com}%'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932317/mysql-email-search-with-boolean-giving-bad-values

Comment: @FahimParkar I need to search the whole email so I cant use just one part

Comment: @Fibonacci : I understand.. try my link... also try [this also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472673/mysql-query-like-returns-nothing)

Comment: @FahimParkar Tried both still returns null, Im sure it's got something to do with the @ but I just cant figure out how to avoid it.

Comment: @Fibonacci : Ok... what I would say just try with `LIKE '%something%'` and see whether you are getting result or not...

Comment: Got it to work with `SELECT * FROM  `myTable` WHERE  `field` LIKE  '%something@something.com%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with

```
SELECT * FROM  `tblTable` WHERE  `field` LIKE  '%something@something.com%'
```

For some reason without the ' in the table name and field name wasn't working

Comment: If your table or column name is a reserved word, you need the backticks to show MySQL that you mean it as, for instance, the column `password` rather than the password() function. Anyway, I think it's a good habit regardless. Incidentally, you can mark your own answer as accepted so the question doesn't keep showing up as "unanswered"

Comment: @IsaacBennetch yeah I know, SO doesn't let me put it as right until tomorrow

Comment: Ah, right, I'd forgotten about the delay. Glad you're up on the procedure; some people aren't so their questions keep popping up in my feed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine. There must be something else wrong.

Try and simplify the query in phpMyAdmin, and search for a specific email address which you know is in the table:

```
SELECT * FROM tblMyTable WHERE field = 'something@something.com'
```

just to make sure that you are looking in the correct table, that the value you seek is there, and that everything is working more or less like it should

Comment: Yep, it is the correct table and value, I was already trying with a value I knew it was there.